# How to query for accounts which have contacts only

Tags: soql

being a new learner im unable to fetch accounts which have contacts only with this Query==> select name,(select lastname form contacts) from account<== with this getting all accounts

Answer (score 3):

Use this query - the outer query looks for Accounts only in the set of Contacts that have an AccountId populated.

```
select id, name from Account where ID IN (select accountId from Contact)
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @salesforceNT This approach (using another query in the `WHERE` clause) is called a "semi join" by Salesforce. There's documentation for this ([comparison operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm) in the SOQL and SOSL reference) in case you want to dig deeper.